# Square root of Complex Numbers to get the roots

Tags: complex-analysis

> ### $$\begin{align} \pm \sqrt{75+30i} & = (75+30i)^{\frac12} \\ & = \left(80\cdot78e^{i(0.121\pi 
>  + 2n\pi)}\right)^{\frac12} 
> \\ & = e ^{\frac12 \left( \ln 80\cdot78 \right) + i(0.121\pi + 2n\pi)\frac12}\end{align}$$

According to picture, should we multiply with both $-1/2$ and $1/2$ to the $e\ln(re^{(i@)})$ form to get the roots? Or just multiply by $1/2$ ? Since the question initially already had plus and minus sign on the square root. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting images.  Images cannot be searched and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  Also, what is eln(re^(i@)) supposed to mean?

Comment: Still new and do not know how to use the Math.Jax. Apologies. That is the polar form of complex numbers. It is convenient when it comes to raising a complex number to some power

Comment: I edited your question to the best of my efforts . Feel free to rollback if I made a mistake.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Make the ansatz $$\sqrt{75+30i}=a+bi$$

Comment: I don't get it. That is more like (a + bi) ^1/2 and (a + bi) ^-1/2